# If $\sec x\tan x<0$, then must we have $\tan x<0$? $\csc x \cot x < 0$? that $x$ is in the third or fourth quadrant?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I had some trouble solving this problem from Barron's Math Level 2 workbook.

> If $(\sec x)(\tan x) < 0$, which of the following must be true?
>
> I. $\tan x < 0$
>
> II. $\csc x \cot x < 0$
>
> III. $x$ is in the third or fourth quadrant

I immediately eliminated Statement I, because either one of the factors, or both of them, could be less than 0, but the question asks for which statements *must* be true.

Statement II, I figured was wrong because the reciprocal of $\sec x \tan x$ is $\cos x \cot x$, not $\csc x \cot x$.

Statement III, however, I did not understand how to definitively prove or disprove. I converted the given expression to $\frac{\sin x}{\cos^2x}$. For it to be less than 0, one of the numerator or denominator must be less than 0. $\sin x$ is positive in Quadrants I and II, so it is negative in III and IV. $\cos^2x$ cannot be negative, so it must be in Quadrants I or IV, where it is positive. Therefore, $\sin x$ must be in Quadrants III and IV (to be negative) and $\cos x$ in Quadrants I or IV (to be positive). Where do I take it from there? The text says choice III is true, only.

Comment: Part III is determined only by the sign of $\sin x$ because $\cos^2 x$ is nonnegative for all $x$ (due to the squaring)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing it as you did, you know that $\cos^2x$ is always positive.  Therefore, the expression is negative if and only if $\sin x$ is negative.  As you note, that happens only in quadrants III and IV, so the third statement is true.

Comment: Another question: For this problem, is it safe to assume that $\cos^2 x \ne 0$?

Comment: @bin No, but for whatever reason we traditionally play fast and loose when talking about whether points on the axes belong to quadrants.

Comment: You can write down that cos(x) ≠ 0. It's fine, because whenever cos(x) is 0, x is 90 degrees, 270 degrees... etc, and x will not lie on any quadrant anyway.